# Handle session while form submission

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web application where users fill the form and a unique id is generated like for example "SC001001". the code for generation is

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT OA_NO FROM student where CUSTID='SC001'");
$x=0;
$num_rows = $result->num_rows;
if($num_rows==0){
    $var1="SC001001";
}
else{

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
 $next[$x]=substr($row['OA_NO'],2);
 $x=$x+1;
  }

$arrlength=count($next);
$inc=max($next)+1;
$newvar= "SC00".$inc;
$var1=$newvar;
}
```

While saving it in the database the OA_NO is the primary key.

but when two users press the submit button at the same time i get the error message #1062. Duplicate entry present and the entry of the first request gets inserted...

my question is how shall i enter both the values with incrementing the second one.. PLEASE HELP!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find the maximum value while doing the insert, the value should always be unique.  I added the `LPAD` function in case you wanted to keep the length of userID consistent:

```
INSERT INTO students (`OA_NO`, `userID`)
SELECT MAX(OA_NO) + 1, CONCAT('SC00', LPAD(MAX(OA_NO) + 1, 4,'0'))
FROM students
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `OA_NO`  = VALUES(OA_NO) + 1, 
    `userID` = CONCAT('SC00', LPAD(VALUES(OA_NO) + 1, 4,'0'));
```

Comment: yes both of the sessions are going simultaneously and the sessions save the same value.. and while insertion one of them gets an error....for duplicate entries

Comment: Try using `ON DUPLICATE KEY`.  The `VALUES` function will get the duplicate ID and increment it by one.  Code updated to reflect.  Also, if you replace `MAX(OA_NO)` with `IFNULL(MAX(OA_NO), 0)` you won't need the extra php logic to generate the first entry if no rows exist.

Comment: hey thanks man.. worked like a charm.. great logic.. THANKS AGAIN..!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't generate a primary key that way.

If you want a sequential numbering, you should use an auto-incremented field as primary key (or as part of the primary key).

Hope it helps

Comment: i dont have a normalized table wherein i have the character id (sc001001) and the auto increment id... and i cant put OA_NO to auto increment as it has a character "S". PLEASE HELP

Comment: if you can use another auto-increment column you can try something like:
`insert into yourtable('OA_NO') select concat('s',max(auto-increment-column)+1) from yourtable`
Then you update with the rest of your data.
Another option could be to use a time function to concat to your prefix.
Clearly if you could use a non-sequential primary key, it would be much easier